# Problem with Unity remains

Tags: unity, 14.10

I have a problem with Ubuntu 14.10. It doesn't load Unity, the Launcher, the Dash, etc. 
I followed the steps given [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears), but the problem remains. I would be grateful if someone could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If nothing worked for you , try loading ttyl by pressing  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+  <kbd>alt</kbd> +  <kbd>f1</kbd> and login in to see if any error is prompted and try to resolve error from there.

Or if even that doesn't work you can always create a new user from the terminal.

`sudo useradd -m username`

`sudo passwd username`

Comment: I created a new user and it works perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: I would really appreciate if you could upvote my answer or mark it as accepted